# Why doesn't Android Studio generate library classes for Dagger or DBFlow?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-studio-4.2

A few days ago I started to experience a weird problem with Android Studio. Every time I try to build my project I keep getting

[image: cannot find symbol class ...]

for each class it should generate. I am using Dagger and DBFlow.

By scrolling all the Build Output logs I am getting

[image]

I tried to add the dependency manually like this

```
implementation group: 'javax.annotation', name: 'javax.annotation-api', version: '1.3.2'
```

but it keeps failing to build.

I also noticed that it keeps changing `languageLevel="JDK_1_8"` to `languageLevel="JDK_11"` in the misc.xml file even though I am using Java 8.

I also tried everything I found here from deleting the .idea folder to uninstalling Android Studio a few times unsuccessfully.

Comment: I am also getting the change from `languageLevel="JDK_1_8"` to `languageLevel="JDK_11"` as of a few weeks ago. Maybe this is a new Android Studio thing. However my app is building fine, so I'm not sure how I can help.

Answer (score 0):

There were other errors in the logs. I had to scroll all of them and look for the one that caused the issue. Once it was fixed everything worked as planned.